# Get CGSize from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my web service response I get the value of one of my JSON key as follows:

```
{
dimensions = "1200, 800";
displayName = "something";
displayNumber = 1;
}
```

I need to convert the dimensions string to a CGSize variable and I use the following code. I got the JSON dictionary to an NSDictionary name wardsDictionary and did the following:

```
NSString *dimensionsString = (NSString *)[wardsDictionary objectForKey:@"dimensions"];
CGSize wardDimensions = CGSizeFromString(dimensionsSizeString);
NSLog(@"the dimensions string: %@",dimensionsString);
NSLog(@"the width: %@ and height:%@", wardDimensions.width, wardDimensions.height);
```

And the result was:

```
the dimensions string: "1200, 800"
the width: 0.0000 and height:0.0000
```

Now what I am trying to do here is to get components separated by "," and get the CGSize variable from it.
But is there a good way to actually achieve this directly?

Comment: If the data is JSON, then sending a pair of numbers as a string with two comma separated values is an awful design. Discuss this with the people responsible for the server. They should send either two numbers with keys "width" and "height", or a dictionary or array with two numbers for the key "dimensions".

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that CGSizeFromString requires the string to be in the format: `"{1200, 800}"` you can either append the brackets to either side, or do the `componentsSeparatedByString:@","` and then get the `intValue` for the components:

```
NSArray *parts = [dimensionsString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
float width = [parts.firstObject floatValue];
float height = [parts.lastObject floatValue];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

Comment: Would recommend using `firstObject` and `lastObject` instead of accessing each "part" by it's index in case the web service's response is incorrect.

Comment: Good point, I was trying to keep the explanation simple. I'll update it

Comment: A better idea would be to confirm that `parts` has two elements in it first.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit your web service, separate dimension key to height & width keys. Then you can easily use those keys to create `CGSize`.

If it's not possible the only way is separate by "," & assign the values to `CGSizeMake`.